# Should [arcsde] tag be renamed to [enterprise-geodatabase]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment we have just over 1,000 questions tagged [arcsde](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcsde) but my understanding is that the product ArcSDE ceased to exist many years ago when it became simply a component of the ArcGIS Server product, and for a few years the component name ArcSDE has been retired in favour of [Enterprise Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/types-of-geodatabases.htm#GUID-3566B58A-5BA3-48BF-91C3-5659948BD619).

Should we rename the [arcsde](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcsde) tag to be called [enterprise-geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-geodatabase), leaving the former as a synonym of the latter?

Comment: ArcSDE application server can still be installed separately from ent gdb if I understand correctly. However 99% of the ArcSDE questions likely deal with ent gdb as Esri has not clearly differentiated the two

Comment: @BradNesom I don't recall even seeing an ArcSDE installer anymore.  Do you mean ArcGIS Server (rather than ArcSDE?)

Comment: With only one answer, and that having a 4:0 vote in favour of the change I have proceeded to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [enterprise-geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-geodatabase) represents what the geodatabase component of ArcGIS Server is, more than the now outdated [arcsde](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcsde).  ArcSDE as a product is now no-more, and so the tag doesn't really fit anymore.

This proposed tag also aligns better with the [file-geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-geodatabase), [personal-geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-geodatabase) as outlined in [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4475/64785) to [Should we treat [spatial-database] and [geodatabase] tags as synonyms?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206)